# scss rgba and loading from css vars;

Tags: javascript, css, sass

Here is a pen of what I am trying to achieve .

I am trying to load css var from js. it works great with the one exception the rgba () function

```
 this.window.document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--color', '#000');
```

This works

```
.no-opacity{
  color: white;
  background: var(--color)
}
```

This does not

```
background: rgba(var(--color), 0.5);
```

In the pen I made it as a mixin but the results are the same.

As you can see the first bar "With opacity" background is not working.
I am loading the css variable using css

https://jsfiddle.net/8dwg7ncy/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's due to the fact that Sass doesn't understand and can't interpret CSS. CSS variables will be taken literal by Sass, the browser will finaly compile the CSS. Therefor `rgba(var(--black), .5)` instead of being compiled to `rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)` will be compiled to `rgba(var(--black), .5)`, assuming you said `--black: #000000;` the browser will no render `rgba(#000000, .5)`, which is not supported in CSS yet.

It's not your JS causing troubles, but Sass being Sass.

Comment: One way around the issue, which is very verbose but will work, is to store the RGB values in three separate variables and interpolate them as such: `background: rgba(var(--colorR, var(--colorG), var(--colorB), 0.5)` for example.

Comment: This gave me an idea , what if i create a sass mixin that destructures the hex in the 3 colors and writes it in the correct way . Gonna try this in a minute and post it here if it works.

Comment: @Rigudi that's possible red($color), green($color), blue($color) will do this for you.

Comment: Thanks for this i found a solution:
When saving the variable I save a second one 

 `const root = this.window.document.querySelector(':root');

        root.style.setProperty(key, value);
       
        if (value.charAt(0) === '#') {
            const rgbValue = hexToRgb(value);
            root.style.setProperty(key+'-rgb', rgbValue);
        }
`
And using it like this 

  `@include rgba-background(--color-rgb, 0.96);`

and it works 
Hex to rgb exports the color like this : `return `${r},${g},${b}`